# numpy use 2 sets as rows and columns of matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

i have 3 arrays
1 has countries

```
['Afghanistan' 'Albania' 'Algeria' 'Andorra' 'Angola' 'Anguilla' .. ]
```

1 has dates

```
['2020-01-01' '2020-01-02' '2020-01-03' '2020-01-04' '2020-01-05' .. ]
```

the other has a data structure like so [country, date, otherField]

```
[['2020-01-01' 'Afghanistan' 'value1']
 ['2020-01-02' 'Afghanistan' 'value2']
 ['2020-01-03' 'Afghanistan' 'value3'] ... ]
```

i need to make a matrix
with countries as rows
dates as columns
and otherField as the corresponding value for each row and column, and I was wondering if there is a cool way to use numpy to do this?

expected output should be something like this:

```
[['' 'Afghanistan' 'Albania' 'Algeria']
['2020-01-01' 'value1' '' '']
['2020-01-02' 'value2' '' '']
['2020-01-03' 'value3' '' '']]
```

Comment: Want is the expected output?

Comment: thanks for the comment, edited it into the question

Comment: The operation you are describing is known as a 'pivot' - libraries like `pandas` support this, I'm not sure if `numpy` has an operation that matches it as simply. Do you need a solution for `numpy` only, or are you happy to use a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `pandas` for this task. This is very simple with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Assuming your input list as `l`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(l).pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2).rename_axis('').reset_index()

out = [list(df.columns)]+df.values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania'],
 ['2020-01-01', 'value1', 'value4'],
 ['2020-01-02', 'value2', 'value5'],
 ['2020-01-03', 'value3', 'value6']]
```

Used input:

```
l = [['2020-01-01', 'Afghanistan', 'value1'],
     ['2020-01-02', 'Afghanistan',  'value2'],
     ['2020-01-03', 'Afghanistan', 'value3'],
     ['2020-01-01', 'Albania', 'value4'],
     ['2020-01-02', 'Albania', 'value5'],
     ['2020-01-03', 'Albania', 'value6'],]
```